# How to post a form with Ajax in Razor Pages

Tags: jquery, razor-pages

I'm new to Razor Pages, so I'm probably asking for something very basic.

I have a Razor Page with a form, which consists of dropdown list and button. It has also one parameter, orderId as route data.

```
<form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Article.Nickname" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Article.ArticleId" class="form-control"
                    asp-items="@Model.ArticleNicknameSL">
                <option value="">-- Select Article--</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Article.ArticleId" class="text-danger" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Article" id="add-article" asp-page-handler="Article" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

There is a PageModel, which constits of this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostArticleAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        ArticlesInOrder newArticleInOrder = new ArticlesInOrder();

        Order = await _context.Orders
            .Include(o => o.Vendor)
            .Include(o => o.ArticlesInOrders)
                .ThenInclude(o => o.Article)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.OrderId == OrderId);

        Article addArticle = await _context.Articles
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.ArticleId == Article.ArticleId);

        newArticleInOrder.Article = addArticle;
        newArticleInOrder.Order = Order;
        newArticleInOrder.Quantity = 1;
        _context.ArticlesInOrders.Add(newArticleInOrder);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return await LoadData();
    }
```

This page works as intended. However, I would like post the form without postback. But I have no idea how to do this. 
Back in my old days with asp.net 4 (web forms), I would just put all inside  tag and puff! It works. But I learned that it is not so easy these day.
I was able to find this: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/form-post and altered the example this way:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#add-article').on('click', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'handler=Article',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function () {
                alert('Posted using jQuery')
            }
        }
        )

        });
    });</script>
```

But it does not do anything useful, just diplays the message from the alert, so I'm obviously missing something. So, what is the proper way to post a form with jquery?

Comment: If the alert is displayed, the AJAX post is working as expected. You need to debug the OnPostArticleAsync handler to see what happens to the posted data. Maybe ModelState is not valid.  It's impossible to tell from the code you posted.

Comment: Ha! Thanks, I was so sure it is not working that I haven't try simple debugging. Anyway, I tried now and problem is that post actually calls another task in Page Model, OnPostAsync. Url in the $.ajax should be '1?handler=Article', not just 'handler=Article', where 1 is orderId in query string. So now I need to figure out how to get data from query string to javascript/jquery

Comment: ...or just add window.location.href and ?handler=Article

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it is actually almost correct. All I need is add window.location.href into url:

```
$(function () {
    $('#add-article').on('click', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: window.location.href + '?handler=Article',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function () {
                alert('Posted using jQuery')
            }
        }
        )

        });
    });
```